# Trying to create an encrypted copy of an ami

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services

I have the following ruby code:

```
sts = Aws::STS::Client.new

stsresp = sts.assume_role(
    :role_arn => _role_arn,
    :role_session_name => "provisioning_vpc_query"
)

ec2 = Aws::EC2::Client.new(
    session_token: stsresp.credentials["session_token"],
    region: _region,
    access_key_id: stsresp.credentials["access_key_id"],
    secret_access_key: stsresp.credentials["secret_access_key"]
)

# ...
p "got image: #{preimage_id}, create encrypted copy..."

resp = ec2.copy_image({
    encrypted: true,
    name: oname,
    source_image_id: preimage_id,
    source_region: _region,
    dry_run: false
})
```

In the code above, preimage_id is a known image in the region _region referenced above.

When I run this, I get:

```
"got image: ami-71e9020b, create encrypted copy..."
Aws::EC2::Errors::InvalidRequest: The storage for the ami is not available in the source region.
```

I can do this manually from the console with no trouble.

Can you help me figure out what's wrong?

Comment: maybe `_region` contains an invalid value?

Comment: More possible errors, https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=246931&tstart=0

Answer (score 0):

turns out, I was attempting to copy the ami before it was 'available'.  Adding a single line to wait did the trick:

```
sts = Aws::STS::Client.new

stsresp = sts.assume_role(
    :role_arn => _role_arn,
    :role_session_name => "provisioning_vpc_query"
)

ec2 = Aws::EC2::Client.new(
    session_token: stsresp.credentials["session_token"],
    region: _region,
    access_key_id: stsresp.credentials["access_key_id"],
    secret_access_key: stsresp.credentials["secret_access_key"]
)

# ...   
p "got image: #{preimage_id}, create encrypted copy..."

ec2.wait_until(:image_available, {image_ids: [preimage_id]})

resp = ec2.copy_image({
    encrypted: true,
    name: oname,
    source_image_id: preimage_id,
    source_region: _region,
    dry_run: false
})
```